# Trouble with urllib calls in Python. Getting server error

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

I am trying to download an XML file from the Eurostat website but I am having trouble using urllib in Python to do it. Somehow when I use my regular Chrome browser it's able to make the HTTP request and the website will generate an XML file, but when I try to do the same thing in python I get a server error. This is the code I am using:

```
import urllib
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
response = urllib.urlopen("http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/data/lfsq_egais/Q.T.Y_GE15.EMP..NL")
result = response.read()
print result
```

I have tried using urllib.urlretrieve too and that didn't work either. Any reason why this might be happening? The HTML I get back is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Draft//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 500--Internal Server Error</TITLE>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="WebLogic Server">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white">
<FONT FACE=Helvetica><BR CLEAR=all>
<TABLE border=0 cellspacing=5><TR><TD><BR CLEAR=all>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica" COLOR="black" SIZE="3"><H2>Error 500--Internal Server Error</H2>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE border=0 width=100% cellpadding=10><TR><TD VALIGN=top WIDTH=100% BGCOLOR=white><FONT FACE="Courier New"><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H3>From RFC 2068 <i>Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1</i>:</H3>
</FONT><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H4>10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error</H4>
</FONT><P><FONT FACE="Courier New">The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.</FONT></P>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Try to catch an Exception, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3351970/1987598).

Comment: The code runs okay, the problem is that the server is not responding to urllib with the XML file I want (that I get when using Chrome). Instead, I get an HTML document detailing the server error ("The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.")

Comment: @joseph - It's not a problem with your code. It's a problem with the server. The server may be expecting some parameters or cookies and throws a 500 instead of returning a more meaningful error page. Here's a suggestion. Try checking the sessions between chrome and the server and see what it is sending that your python code isn't sending.

Comment: @joseph - I just checked, but using the URL you just pasted sends back an error message in xml that says `"Error caused by the caller due to incorrect or semantically invalid arguments"`.

Comment: @alvits ok that should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a few months old now, but better late than never:

The Eurostat REST API you are talking is supposed to respond with XML content, which urllib is not expecting/allowing by default. The solution is to add a header `Accept: application/xml` to the request.

This will do the trick in Python 2.7 (using `urllib2` by the way):

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request("http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/data/"
    "lfsq_egais/Q.T.Y_GE15.EMP..NL")
req.add_header("Accept", "application/xml")
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

See [urllib2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) for more info and examples.